How to describe with JSDoc a variable in which a Pinia store is defined?
A simple code for instance:
file: @/stores/alerts.js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useAlertsStore = defineStore('alerts', {
  // other options...
  actions: {
    addAlert() { ... }
  }
})
...

file: @/views/myComponent.vue
import { useAlertsStore } from '@/stores/alerts'
...

/**
 * The type of the alertStore variable is expected to be defined here
 */
const alertsStore = useAlertsStore()
...

alertsStore.addAlert(...);
...

The question is how to describe with JSDoc variable alertsStore?
Something like @type {AlertsStore}
Updated

Depends on the intention of jsdoc. Potentially ReturnType. Not sure how good this works with tools that support jsdoc but it's compatible with TS at least

@EstusFlask I need it for type checking.
When I try to do what you suggest, vue-tsc throws error - Type 'Store<"alerts", { ... } is not assignable to type 'StoreDefinition<"alerts", { ... }.
And also vue-tsc throws an error when I try to call the action addAlert from the store - Property 'addAlert' does not exist on type 'StoreDefinition<"alerts", { ... }.

How is vue-tsc involved? If you use TS, it makes sense to really use it, its jsdoc support is a compromise. Does the error occur when you use no jsdoc? This is the case when I'd expect one to not be needed. Pinia is suited for inferred types

We use JSDoc + vue-tsc for type checking. Convenient for them who do not accept TS. The error occur when running script npm run check-types ( package.json -> scripts -> "check-types:dev": "vue-tsc --noEmit" )

An article about type checking with JSDoc + tsc - https://medium.com/@trukrs/type-safe-javascript-with-jsdoc-7a2a63209b76

You may notice the article is dated. jsdoc+ts is a half-measure that lacks development. Currently TS is pretty much de facto, the devs who prefer vanilla JS just provide .d.ts declaration to be compatible with both. You didn't answered about the condition under which the error occurs. Does const alertsStore = useAlertsStore(); alertsStore.addAlert(...) cause an error? Usually it's a function that produces a value that needs to be typed in TS, not a variable as you tried. Considering that useAlertsStore itself is produced with properly typed defineStore, I'd expect nothing needs to be done

Perhaps I was misunderstood. I didn't mean the application error. I just get type checking error when add jsdoc description to alertsStore variable like this - /** @type {useAlertsStore} */ const alertsStore = useAlertsStore()
Type checking is built into our CI/CD pipeline

Do you have problems when there's no jsdoc for this variable?

No problem if there is no jsdoc for this variable. And I have to not add jsdoc to avoid a type check error, which is sad.

Then this is the way it's intended. Types aren't often needed for local variables in jsdoc. And as said, Pinia is TS-friendy, and you can rely on inferred types instead of explicitly typing them, unless you have an interface which you implement. Since jsdoc is used in the context of TS compiler here, I'd expect it to be like that. And by the way, did you try @type {useAlertsStore} all the way? It's wrong type in both jsdoc and ts, at least in TS it should have been ReturnType, this probably translates to  @type {ReturnType<useAlertsStore>}, not sure about jsdoc

Well, adding jsdoc gives one more benefit - during coding, the IDE can give smarter hints if variables are well-typed with jsdoc

IDEs rely on TS, especially VSC, and I expect it to retain type info for inferred types even in .js in this case. Did you test this? This is very specific to how it's implemented in in specific IDE because TS-based tools differ in a way they work.

@type {ReturnType<useDbQueueStore>} works better, thanks a lot! It does not causes type check error but unfortunately it does not help IDE to give smarter hints.
As an IDE I use Intellij IDEA.
VSC better works with jsdoc+ts but IDEA has other advantages that I'm not willing to part with
